# Who authored the 13 Ani Maamin's?

Tags: song-poetry, rambam, authorship, ikarim

The Rambam in his Hakdama to his Pirush on Perek Chelek in Mesechtas Sanhedrin mentions the points of belief a Jew must have. To the best of my knowledge these are the basis of the well-known formulation known as "Ani Maamin" before the first words in each phrase. Who authored this wording of the principles?

Comment: No one knows.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: You have the workings of an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA "poetic"?

Comment: @ba Seems like a piyut of sorts to me. They all start with the same wording.

Comment: @ba lol wikipedia calls it prosaic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ani_Ma%27amin I don't really care that much. You can edit if you want. It certainly is an ordered formulation.

Comment: It was written by a fellow named Aaaaaaaaaaaaa, who cleverly hid his name within the composition in the form of an acrostic.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2007/07/sz-havlin-additional-notes-on-new.html

Comment: I believe that some suggest Rabbi Immanuel of Rome as the author.

Comment: I always thought it was the rambam himself

Answer (score -2):

The Nusach was compiled by an anonymous author and was first inserted in the beginning of modern history in many Siddurim.

Example [Siddur Krakow](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22567&pgnum=480) שנת ה'שנ"ז

[הניסוח חובר על ידי מחבר אנונימי, והוכנס בראשית העת החדשה לתוך רבים מסידורי התפילה](https://www.hamichlol.org.il/%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F).

Comment: You could do much better at citing this. This appears to be your own translation of a line form Wikipedia and their example, but it's not clear from your citation formatting that the English is a translation of the presented Hebrew nor that you took their example.