# What is the source of saying Ani Maamin daily?

Tags: prayer-book, faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim

Many Siddurim have the 13 principles of faith after Shacharit. Where do we find a source for its daily recitation?

Comment: I believe they are an abridged version of the Rambam's 13 principles of faith. (see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13091, https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/332555/jewish/Maimonides-13-Principles-of-Faith.htm

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/who-authored-the-13-ani-maamins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most well known source is Rav Yaakov Emden in his [Siddur Yaavetz](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=188&book=12984) who writes:

> ״הירא את דבר ה' אומר זה בכל יום, ויכוין היטב בכל עיקר, ויאמינו בלב שלם
> בלא פניה, ויזכה לאור באור החיים הנצחיים״

Rav Avraham Tzvi Friedman in his [Otzar Halachos](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=90&book=61454) writes that the minhag of the Tzanzer Rav was to say the piyut of Ani Maamin 3 times a day, once after birkas hatorah, twice after shacharis with tallis and tefillin, and a third time before kriyas shema al hamitah.